# How to print out all contents of Facebook GraphUser object on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using `Facebook SDK for Android`. I'm wondering if there's a way to echo or print all the contents of the `GraphUser` object into a `TextView`. For example like using `print()` on `PHP` arrays/objects. Here's my request method:

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
           helloUser.setText("Welcome, "+user.getName()+"!");
        }
    }
});
```

I'd like to see all the contents/formatting of the `User` object before parsing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is `user` then you can do this:

```
user.toString()
```